# Get video call logs data of Twillio

Tags: php, laravel, twilio

I'm trying to get logs of video-calling that are in the URL of `https://www.twilio.com/console/video/api/logs/rooms/csv`. I'm trying the following code to do that, but in return, I'm getting 0 responses. How can we get the this data via Laravel?

```
   $sid    = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    $token  = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    $twilio = new Client($sid, $token);    
    $calls = $twilio->calls
    ->read([], 20);
    Log::info($twilio);
    Log::info($twilio->calls);
    Log::info($calls);
```

Is there any way to get this data in PHP with Laravel?

Comment: How is this related to Laravel? Have you tried debugging the API connector itself before checking how to integrate it into another framework?

Comment: Because I'm using integrating it with Laravel. and yes, still not getting anything that why I'm not getting any response from this.

Comment: The above code you provided is for Call Logs, not Video Logs.

Answer (score 1):

That is not the REST API resource, so not sure where you got that URL from?
`https://www.twilio.com/console/video/api/logs/rooms/csv`.

The REST resources are shown below.

[REST API: Rooms](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource)

[REST API: Participants](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/participants)

[REST API: PublishedTrack](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/publishedtrack)

- This show active tracks (not when the meeting is completed)